# Angular 4 - Get und Set ng-model

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-model, ngoninit

I am trying to get and set a boolean to 'checkvalue'. I want beforehand  to call a function isItTrue to set the variable 'checkvalue'. If the box is (un)checked/ and I check it, it should call a function doSomething().
I was experimenting with `<input type="checkbox" id="{{ class.id }}" ng-init="checkBoxValue=isItTrue(class.id)"[(ngModel)]="class['checkBoxValue']"/>` but it doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>class</th>
        <th>subjects</th>
        <th>class speaker</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let class of classes">
        <td>{{ class.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="form">
            <input type="text" class="md-input-text" placeholder=" " value=" " [(ngModel)]="subject"/>
            <label class="md-desc">subjects</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="md-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ class.id }}" [(ngModel)]="class['checkBoxValue']"/>
            <label for="{{ class.id }}"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: ng-init is not Angular thing anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

**To do something on the component initialization:**

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

And make your component implement it like

```
export class App implements OnInit{ 
}
```

and you can call your method from the ngOnInit lifecycle hook method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    isItTrue();
}
```

**Setting a boolean to checkvalue:**
You should have a component variable and bind it to the input with:

```
[(ngModel)]="checkvalue"
```

**To call your function when the input changes, you can achieve it with the change event:**

```
(change)="doSomething()"
```

In this function, you can access the value of the input with `this.checkvalue` which you already binded.

Seee this [planker](https://plnkr.co/edit/J78SxouA2bHoO1pVwhyc?p=preview) for the whole code. Hope it helps :).